Redondear a 2 decimales
Deseo saber, cómo es que puedo agregar específicamente 2 números decimales -> 100."24" de está manera dentro de Math.round(importeCompra "que agrego para que me salga eso dos decimales")|ya lo intente por 100 entre 100|, mi profesor me lo dejo con un tipo tarea y no encuentro una solución, además comento que son dos cosas que se agregan
Math.round(importeCompra"Acá es donde necesito agregar algo pequeños dice para tener dos decimales")

Se me ocurre Math.round(valor * 100) / 100 para salir del paso.

Pues primero, agregar que código has intentado, y un ejemplo de lo que esperas obtener.

¿No crees que muchas preguntas podrían ser tituladas Pregunta sobre Java?  Está bien que en título sea breve, pero por favor evitemos títulos tan abarcativos.

@Mateo Sobre los titulos, no, no es necesario mencionar que es de java, dado que esta con su tag correcto, el cual aparece en el listado de tags.

@Excorpion El titulo lo cambie yo, el antiguo decía "Pregunta sobre Java" de ahí el comentario de Mateo

Ahhh entendible, gracias Yussef :3

Un "valor" y su representación son cosas distintas, por ejemplo el 10 en binario y el 2 en decimal son en esencia el mismo valor, pero con visualizaciones distintas.
Digo esto, porque tu pregunta tiene al menos 2 soluciones distintas
1) Cambiar solo la representación visual
Imagina tenemos una table con valores, por ejemplo un reporte o una factura. No queremos mostrar muchos decimales, porque visualmente confunden. No obstante, tampoco queremos redondear el valor ya que la propagación de este redondeo puede generar errores en los valores finales.
Mira este ejemplo en excel:

Fíjate que 2.3 + 3.3 = 5.7 (no 5.6), porque realmente los valores originales son 2.33333 + 3.333333 = 5.666663, no hemos cambiado el número, solo su representación visual
Esto en java, puede realizarse a lo menos de 2 maneras
1.1) Usando DecimalFormat
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double numero = 123.456789;
        DecimalFormat formato = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
        System.out.println(formato.format(numero)); //123,46
    }
}

1.2) String.format
public static void main(String[] args) {
  double numero = 123.456789;
  String redondeado = String.format("%.2f", numero);
  System.out.println(redondeado);  //123,46
}

2) Cambiar el valor
Todo lo anterior puede no interesarte, tu lo que quieres es un número nuevo redondeado. Para esto puedes hacer lo que te señalo @CandidMoe en su comentario, que es multiplicar por 100; y si fueran 3 decimales sería por 1000, con 4 decimales por 10000 y así sucesivamente. Luego aplicar Math.round que redondeará al entero más cercano y luego dividimos por el mismo factor aplicado al principio (100 en el caso de 2 decimales)
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double numero = 123.456789;
    double redondeado = Math.round(numero * 100.0) / 100.0;
    System.out.println(redondeado); //123.46
}

